# Update fields on a form when a checkbox is selected

Tags: sql-update

I need to copy data from physical address fields in a table to mailing address fields in the same table if a checkbox is selected on a form.  It seems like this would be very easy; however, I keep trying different things and nothing works.

When I click on the checkbox on my first record in the form, nothing gets updated.  When I go to the second record on the form and select the checkbox, the first record in the table gets updated instead of the second record in the table.  Also, I can’t get the updated records to show on the form when the checkbox is selected even though the new updated records get updated in the table.

Right now I have a macro attached to the On Click of the checkbox and the macro is supposed to run a SQL query.

My SQL query is:

```
UPDATE tblVenues 
SET ContactMailingAddress = ContactPhysicalAddress, ContactMailingSuite = ContactPhysicalSuite, ContactMailingCity = ContactPhysicalCity, ContactMailingState = ContactPhysicalState, ContactMailingZip = ContactPhysicalZip, ContactMailingCountry = ContactPhysicalCountry
WHERE ContactMailingAddressSame = true;
```

My macro is:

```
OpenQuery
Qry Name: qrySQLUpdateMailingAddresses
View Datasheet
Data Mode Edit
Stop Macro
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: macro where? in what? what db?

Comment: Microsoft Access DB.  SQL query per what I posted.  Form has checkbox. When the checkbox on the form is selected, I am trying to run the SQL query.  Obviously it is not working.  I had created a macro to run On Click on the checkbox on the form to try to run the SQL query.  Again, obviously not working.